# Where is the "HMAppDelegate.m" file? - Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to follow these instructions:

- Edit the HMAppDelegate.m file. In the line:
- [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
- Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your key.

Problem is I don't know where to find the HMAppDelegate.m file.

SOLVED: iIt was located in a folder called "Classes"

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in `hellomap-ios / HelloMap`? See [this link](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-ios/blob/master/HelloMap/HMAppDelegate.m) for more information.

Hope this helps!